# Rishonim and lomdus

Tags: rishonim, lomdus

Did the rishonim appreciate the intricate way of learning with lomdus?
To ask it with an example; would the rashba appreciate opening a reb baruch ber?

Comment: I would contend that the derech of the rishonim superceded lomdus. They knew exactly what they wanted to say and they said it. Lomdus is just reverse-engineering that. It's like learning physics without calculus: you need to thumb-dip your way through algebra a whole lot more to get the same idea, while the language of calculus will tell you the answer directly.

Comment: Common thread seemed to be getting to halacha l'maaseh...

Comment: Much of lomdus is just a way of precisely describing what the Rishonim meant.